# Bootstrap node using java

Tags: java, chef-infra, bootstrapping

i am new with chef

I created a cookbook for bootstrap VMs, this cookbook will create configuration files, download services and packages and install it in the nodes,

I wonder if there is a way to bootstrap VMs with this configuration from Java implimentation instead of used "knife bootstrap" , thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Jclouds includes some code to do this, though there isn't a lot of docs on it. Check the jclouds-example project on github.